# How do I get rows with value1 in column1 and value2 in column2 but value2 in column1 does not have value1 in column2?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `contacts`:

```
user_id     contact_id
10294       10295
10294       10293
10293       10294
10295       10296
10296       10294
10297       10296
10298       10295
10295       10294
10293       10297
```

How can I select the rows from this table where `user_id` has a `contact_id` but the feeling is not reciprocated - I mean that `contact_id` does not have `user_id` as a `contact_id`?

For example in the above case `$user_id` is `10295`. The row I want is

```
   10295       10296
```

I can select all rows with `user_id` as `10295` with:

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts 
        WHERE user_id = ?";  

        $stmt2 = $con->prepare($sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $stmt2->bind_param('i', $user_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
        $stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);

        $privateReviews = $stmt2->get_result();
```

It would give me:

```
10295       10296
10295       10294
```

But I am looking for just: `10295       10296`.

How can I do this?

Comment: The title of this question is extremely confusing. Where is `1095`, and/or how does that relate to `10295 10296`?

Comment: `1095` is `$user_id`, which is posted from my app. If you have a better title, please suggest. It's the most specific I could think of! Something like, `Problem with Select statement` would be too generic.

Comment: One oh nine five. As opposed to one oh two nine five

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
select *
from contacts
where user_id = ?
  and (user_id, contact_id) not in (
  select contact_id, user_id from contacts
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a clever and efficient way to do this directly in sql (sure is, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56519273/2149955)). My approach would be to make a second query. Your first query gets all the contacts that the querying user has added. The second query would do the reverse and look up all the users who have added the user we are querying for.

Then compare those two lists, in this case you want all the elements in the 2nd list that aren't in the first.

```
// This line is changed
$sql = "SELECT contact_id FROM contacts 
WHERE user_id = ?";

// these lines are unchanged
$stmt2 = $con->prepare($sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$stmt2->bind_param('i', $user_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
$stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);

// changed this variable name
$usersThisUserHasAdded = $stmt2->get_result(); 

//new lines
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM contacts 
WHERE contact_id = ?";
$stmt3 = $con->prepare($sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$stmt3->bind_param('i', $user_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt3->error);
$stmt3->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt3->error);

$usersWhoHaveAddedThisUser = $stmt3->get_result();

$usersWhoHavedAddedThisUserUnreciprocated = array_diff($usersWhoHaveAddedThisUser, $usersThisUserHasAdded);

// $usersWhoHavedAddedThisUserUnreciprocated should now have all the users we are looking for, if you want this in a different format or as some selection of rows you should be able to format it yourself with the original nuser ID or query the rows again using this list
```